# Python monkey patch private function

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I have a module with a function (call it `a()`) that calls another function defined in the same module (call it `__b()`).  `__b()` is a function which speaks to a website via `urllib2` and gets some data back.  Now I'm trying to test `a()`, but of course would rather not have my unit tests speak to the public internet.  Thus, I'm thinking if I can monkey patch `__b()` with a function which returns canned data, then I can write the tests for `a()`.

To be more concrete, my module looks kinda like:

```
def a():
    return __b("someval")

def __b(args):
    return something_complex_with_args
```

So now I want to test `a()`, but I need to monkey patch out `__b`.  The problem is that A) the vast majority of information on monkey patching applies to methods of a class, not to functions in a module, and B) the function I want to monkey patch is private.  I am willing to change `__b` to be non-private if it makes the process more feasible, but would rather not.

Suggestions?

Edit: as it stands the test class looks like:

```
from unittest import TestCase

import mymodule

def newfn(args):
    return {"a" : "b"}

mymodule._b = newfn

class TestMyModule(TestCase):
    def test_basic(self):
        print(mymodule.a('somearg'))
```

And when I run this, I see the output if the monkey patching had not been done at all, rather than seeing `{'a': 'b'}` get printed out.

Comment: In general, if *anything* outside the module needs to access a function (including tests), you probably shouldn't be using `__name` format. Use `_name` format instead to signify that it's an internal function while still making it possible for the things that do need to access it to get at it.

Comment: Name mangling (`__x`) is not the same as *private* and you unless you know exactly what it is, you probably shouldn't be using it. Python does not have data hiding.

Comment: @Lattyware: I'm aware that it's not the same thing as private, but it's as close as it gets.  Why is there the concern about having it named with double underscore?

Comment: @AdamParkin Because the dobule underscore provides name mangling - the name gets changed (look up to docs for why and exactly what happens). You don't need to make things private in Python. Your problem is a very clear example of why it's a bad idea. Python isn't Java or C++, and writing it as though it is will result in bad code.

Comment: By "to docs" do you mean (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private)? So then I still fail to see why it's generally bad.  Perhaps move this to chat since it's not particularly relevant to my question?

Answer (score 4):

I can't seem to reproduce your issue (I've tweaked your example a bit, since it doesn't run at all as-is).  Did you just mistype something (like `mymodule._b` instead of `mymodule.__b`)?

**mymodule.py**:

```
def a(x):
    return __b("someval")

def __b(args):
    return "complex_thingy: {}".format(args)
```

**mytest.py**:

```
from unittest import TestCase

import mymodule

def newfn(args):
    return {"a" : "b"}

mymodule.__b = newfn

class TestMyModule(TestCase):
    def test_basic(self):
        print(mymodule.a('somearg'))
```

**Output**:

```
C:\TEMP>python -m unittest mytest
{'a': 'b'}
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK

C:\TEMP>
```

**Seems to work fine.**

---

Or outside of unittest:

**mytest2.py**:

```
import mymodule

def newfn(args):
    return {"a" : "b"}

mymodule.__b = newfn

print(mymodule.a('somearg'))
```

**Output**:

```
C:\TEMP>python mytest2.py
{'a': 'b'}

C:\TEMP>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your module was named 'foo', then the following should work.

```
import foo

def patched_version():
    return 'Hello'

foo.__b = patched_version

print (foo.a())
```

where foo.py is

```
def a():
    return __b()

def __b():
    return 'Goodbye'
```

Comment: Nope, original version of __b() is still called (regardless of whether it's `__b` or `_b`).

Comment: Looking into this a bit more, your answer works, but when I change the print to be inside a test method (like in my question), the original version of `__b` is called.

Comment: It's because unittest executes very differently than 'normal' Python. Try putting the `foo.__b = patched_version` in a `setUp` function for your test. If you're using something other than `unittest`, YMMV.

Comment: I am using `unittest` and moving it into `setUp` did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, but finally got to the solution. The problem was when using the monkey patch in the unittest.TestCase class. Here's the solution that works just fine:

If you are using Python 2, you'll need to install the "mock" library (http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) using easy_install or some other way. This library is already bundled with Python 3.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
from mock import patch

    class TestMyModule(TestCase):
        def test_basic(self):
            with patch('mymodule._b') as mock:
                mock.return_value={"a" : "b"} # put here what you want the mock function to return. You can make multiple tests varying these values.
                #keep the indentation. Determines the scope for the patch.
                print(mymodule.a('somearg'))
```

Although this way apparently seems a bit less convenient compared to making a mock function where we could mimic the actual sub-function, _b(), having logic to return different values based on different arguments, but then we unnecessarily add more chances of error. In this approach we just hard-code what we want our mocked function to return and test the actual function we set out to test, that was a().

Comment: Nope, still didn't work for me.  I get: `AttributeError: <module 'mymodule' from 'mymodule/__init__.py'> does not have the attribute '_b'`  Adding the "private" function to __init__.py made the error go away, but then the patching had no effect (original version was still being called).